# eledmac et seq (f., ff.) and footnote without lemma

Tags: eledmac

I needed to implement to "hacks" into eledmac as I have to follow a pre-existing layout. I came up with a solution, where I want a critical oversight, as I'm certain that it is an ugly one, as you can see through the use of \hspace.

1.) Critical footnotes referencing more than one line should denote as "5f."/"5ff." instead of "5-6" or "5-9". This saves space and is common practice in German editions.

2.) I'm preparing an edition where a new chapter has been introduced in a later print of the book. This of course happens between lines. So if a new chapter is introduced after line 112 I don't have a lemma to attach this to. Instead it should read: "112/113 Chapter seperation introduced in 3rd edition".

The first one is easy, i use a counter for it. The second one was more difficult, i misused the value of the first pagemark and set it to -1.

```
    \documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\firstlinenum{0} \linenumincrement{1}

\newcounter{inbetween}

\makeatletter
\def\printlines#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|{%
\setcounter{inbetween}{#2}
\stepcounter{inbetween}
\begingroup
\setprintlines{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
\ifnum#5>\value{inbetween}\hspace{-1em}{#2}ff. \else       % This line is new
\ifnum#5=\value{inbetween}\hspace{-0.5em}{#2}f. \else
\ifnum#1=-1 \hspace{-0.5em}{#2}/\arabic{inbetween} \else \ifnum#5=#2 \hspace{-0.5em}{#2} \fi \fi \fi
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\insertpartmark}{\edtext{}{\linenum{-1}\Afootnote[nosep]{\hspace{-1em}New chapter mark introduced in 3rd edition}}}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering      
\pstart
\edtext{What}{\Afootnote{Whit}} a \edtext{piece}{\Afootnote{peace}} of work is man! how noble in reason! 
\pend
\pstart
Dann bekleidete sie mit seinen weichen, weiten Filz
pantoffeln, in denen sie versanken, \edtext{ihre Fuesschen,}{\Afootnote{test}}
welche von Kuessen verwundet waren, und stampfte gravitaetisch
mit einer sehr wuerdigen und kaiserlichen Miene und sang, indem sie mit dem Kopfe den Takt dazu pendelte, ein altes feierliches Kirchenlied. Aber plötzlich, aufrecht auf einem Beine, schnellte sie mit dem Schwunge des andern den Schuh hoch, um ihn durch eine flinke und zuversichtliche Gebaerde wieder aufzufangen. In dieser anmutigen Pose verweilte sie. Sie stiess den Laden nach dem Garten auf, aus welchem der Flieder suesse Gruesse schickte.{\insertpartmark}
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: hi, that is not a question, and I don't think root will apprecate it. But in a any case, thanks for sharing. However, as maintener of eledmac I will answer. Eledmac, instead of old ledmac, was conceptualized to prevent user to hacks default feature, but use instead what I called "hook" (defines in 4.4 Display options section). That prevent to have many hack in many direction, and complexity for user. So I will ask you to open an issue on github in order to add this feature nativly in eledmac. I will also ask you to explain better the 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I have explained, I try to avoid hacks. In the past, many users provided hack to ledmac, and it was difficult for new users to find the way to make them compatible. That's why I have created eledmac, which provides "hooks" (explained in the section Display options of the handbook), which are setting to customize not displaying.

In this case you have requirement for new hooks and for help with the current feature. So I will resume you need and the answer.

**1. Use f. and ff. instead of print final line number**

When you have posted, only you hack could do it. With he new version of eledmac, 1.20.0, just uploaded on CTAN, you have new feature.

1. a `\twolines` hook. Used as `\twolines{f.}`.
2. a `\morethantwolines` hook. Used as `\morethantwolines{ff.}`.

**2. In some specific case, print final line number**

Linked to the previous. I have added `[fulllines]` options to `\Afootnote` `\Bfootnote` etc.   to skip the two previous hooks.

**3. Use / instead of --.**

That can be already done by redefing `\endashchar`. I won't add hooks to customize it by series, except if you ask for it.

**4. Allow to refer to a line where the edtext is not called**

Use `\edlabel{xx}` to mark the first line, `\edlabel{yy}` to mark the the last, and use `\xxref{xx}{yy}` inside the second arg of `\edtext.

**5. Don't print space when lemma separator is not printed**

The best way is to compensat the afterlemmaseparator by using hook `\inplaceoflemmaseparator{-0.5em}`